# Z-index display issue

Tags: css

I have a #container with a background and the z-index set to 0.
On top of that, there's a #content with a background which repeats vertically, and has z-index set to -1, so it sits behind the header graphics.
However, I want the content itself to sit on top of all this, so I set the #main's z-index to 1. By the way, nevermind the body's fixed background.
As you can see here http://goo.gl/NUeG7 the result is not what I had in mind, I read many things but can't seem to figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-index doesnt work for elements with "position: static". You have to use "position: relative"

Comment: unfortunately that didn't fixed it, I'll keep trying though